# Generate WCF (windows service hosted) client proxy class with XML comments?

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, intellisense, svcutil.exe

I have a small problem which I haven´t found a solution to. I'm developing a simple WCF service (VS2010, .NET 4.0, windows service hosted).

I have no control over the client side, and therefore I need to make it as simple as possible for the programmer to use my WCF service.

My idea is to just provide the client side programmer with the url you get when I browse to my service. `svcutil.exe http://localhost:7070/Historian.WCFSvc/mex`.

The problem is that when I generate the proxy class executing the svcutil.exe on the url I don't get the XML-comments for the intellisense?!?!

I googled around and stumbled upon this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717040.aspx

I stole the code from the sample project but I quickly realized that just providing the url to my service is not enough.

I don't really understand how to make it work, how to pass the WsdlDocumentation attributes to the generated proxy class?! I guess I need a guide or similar that walks me through this. Has anyone used this sample code and perhaps help me with a walkthrough?

The download page for the sample code is located at the bottom of the page I linked to. (Since I'm new here I can only post one link...sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the below for a while to generate my proxy classes and they seem to inherit the xml comments, perhaps you coud try this

```
svcutil /t:metadata http://localhost:7070/Historian.WCFSvc/mex
svcutil /t:code *.wsdl *.xsd /out:Proxy.cs /config:Proxy.config
```

Good luck :)